# Vue js Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to make my vue component as flexible as possibile, So i have some button and a search i need to use on all my table component . For now it is hard coded, but i wnat to make it more flexible, everything work until now except the search . I see an error like this on console

`ERROR:`  `[Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "query"`

I know the problem is when i try to change the query input but does now know how to fix this problem. Does anyone know ?

```js
//custom action buttons
import Button from './button.js';

export default {
    components: {
        'v-button': Button
    },

    props: {
        query: {
          type: String
        },
        selected: {
            type: Array
        },
        url: {
            type: String
        }
    },

    // props: [
    //     'selected',
    //     'query',
    //     'url'
    // ],

    methods: {
        showModal() {
            this.$emit('showModal')
        },

        massDeleteRecord() {
            this.$emit('massDeleteRecord')
        }
    },

    template: `
        <div class="add-user py-4">
            <div class="d-flex">
                <div class="col-10">
                    <v-button type="success" @click.prevent="showModal" >
                        Add Record
                    </v-button>
                    <v-button type="primary" data-mdb-toggle="collapse" data-mdb-target="#collapseFilter" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseFilter" >
                        Filter
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-filter"></i>
                    </v-button>
                    <v-button v-show="selected.length>0" type="danger" class="dropdown dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-mdb-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" >
                            Action ({{selected.length}})
                    </v-button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                        <li>
                            <a :href="url" class="dropdown-item btn-warning text-center">
                                Export
                                <i class="fa-solid fa-file-excel"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <v-button @click="massDeleteRecord()" type="danger" class="dropdown-item text-center">
                                Delete
                                <i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i>
                            </v-button>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-2">
                    <input @input="$emit('updatedQuery', $event.target.value)" 
                        :value="query"
                        type="search"
                        class="form-control border-0"
                        placeholder="Search"
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    `,
}
```

User Table Component

```html
<template>
<table-custom-action 
   @massDeleteRecord="massDeleteUser" 
   @showModal="showModal" 
   @updated-query="(newQuery) => query = newQuery"
   :selected="selected"
   :query="query"
   :url="url"
 ></table-custom-action>
</template>

<script>
import TableCustomAction from './partials/modules/TableCustomAction.js';
export default {
        components: {
            TableCustomAction,
        },
        
        data(){
            return {
                ....
                query: '',
                ....
                url: ''
            }
        },  
watch: {
            query: function(newQ, old) {
                if (newQ === "") {
                    this.getRecord();
                } else {
                    this.searchRecord();
                }
            },
        },
</script>
```

Comment: The same question is here, maybe it will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74287855/vue2-avoid-mutating-a-prop-directly-since-the-value-will-be-overwritten

Comment: it does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using `v-model` on `query`, send back the update to the parent. It will update in the parent, be transferred through the props to your child and produce the same result. If you mutate it in the child, then it will at some point mutate in the parent, hence do twice the work.
Here is a [nice article](https://michaelnthiessen.com/avoid-mutating-prop-directly/) on the subject.

---

Also, you [don't update props](https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/no-mutating-props.html) actually, they are read-only.

In the child

```html
<input @input="$emit('updatedQuery', $event.target.value)" 
  :value="query"
  type="search"
  class="form-control border-0"
  placeholder="Search"
/>
```

In the parent

```html
<table-custom-action @updated-query="(newQuery) => query = newQuery">
</table-custom-action>
```

UPDATE: here is a [working repro](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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).

---

More details here in [the doc](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html#emitting-and-listening-to-events).

Comment: I tryed this method but does not work for me. Also i see component on vue `query: ""` is empty

Comment: @leoon0012 please be more explicit regarding the "not work". Also, I'm not sure to understand the last part of your comment. I recommend that you double check with your Vue devtools to find out what is missing.

Comment: I check on vue devtools, on `table-custom-action` component i see `query props` but is empty `query:""` . I know about emiting event with vue js , i just does not understand how i should use there on this search query. I think i need  to populate also the `query` on data of parent component?

Comment: @leoon0012 got a small typo, fixed my code. Can you please check the linked repro?

Comment: i just updated my question so you can see all changers i have done. I have copy what you have done on example repo but it does not work for me. On vue devtool i see query still is not updated

Comment: @leoon0012 shouldn't it be `partials/modules/TableCustomAction.vue`? Do you see the emitted event? Is there a parent/child relationship between the 2? Do you have any ESlint error?

Comment: I have made my child component as javascript module, and place inside `partials/modules...` And no i does not see any error. All other functions work good,as selected option witch select all reecord an the url witch is used to export data on excel

Comment: Not sure how it works with JS modules, I always use `.vue` SFC. Do you see the emitted event in your devtools? Try to replace `updatedQuery` by `test` for the emit + listener, maybe it's a missing compiler case thing. Strange that the rest works but not this part, nothing special about it @leoon0012

Comment: Yes this work. Maybe ther was the problem maybe misscompiler, i just change the name fo emit and it work